# Is it possible to sink and source from one output pin using a darlington driver

Tags: pic, driver, darlington, sourcing, sinking

[Sinking and sourcing with a darlington driver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209157/sinking-and-sourcing-with-a-darlington-driver)

I asked a question about sinking and sourcing LEDs while using a darlington driver. The images were slightly unclear so i have redrawn it. I had too many LEDs in my circuit so i needed to create a relay. I am going to use a darlington driver and when i was testing it, i was fine with all other 7 outputs. However, I am unsure how to be able to sink and source LEDs from 1 output pin while using a Darlington driver

My project is a traffic light. I have 8 available outputs. I have 9 groups of LEDs. Currently there is 5v availible for the LEDs. The maximum number of leds per group is 8. I also have a loudspeaker and a motor in there. Please see comments for LEDs data sheet
[image: This is where i am at the moment]

ww.picaxe.com/Circuit-Creator/General-Outputs/Darlington-Driver-ULN2803A/

That is the link for the Darlington Driver i am using which is represented by the 18 - DIL

[image: This is the schematic with the ULN2803A in place]

Is it possible to sink and source at the same time with the driver?

I only have 8 outputs and i realised that either the green man or the red man can be on at the same time. So to maximise outputs i sunk the red LEDs and sourced the green LEDs. However, I realised i had too many LEDs to work with a 5v PIC, so i needed to create a relay

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to create an LED matrix of some sort?

Comment: Its a light display

Comment: You need to give a much better response than that if you want help. Of course it's a light display. The giveaway is in 'LEDs'.

Comment: Its a traffic control system. Basically a traffic light, with a countdown, and motor to aid the visually impaired. The waiting times are controlled by light levels.

Comment: @transistor I only have 8 outputs and i realised that either the green man or the red man can be on at the same time. So to maximise outputs i sunk the red LEDs and sourced the green LEDs. However, I realised i had too many LEDs to work with a 5v PIC, so i needed to create a relay

Comment: The negative terminals of the two batteries must be connected together, along with the ULN2803 ground pin.

Comment: @PeterBennett Do you know why that is? That both batteries need to be connected

Comment: You need a common reference voltage between the two parts of your circuit.  You must always "put current back where you got it" - without a common ground, the output current from the PIC to the ULN2803 can't make it back to the PIC, so the ULN2803 transistors won't turn on.

Comment: @HasanImtiaz: OK. Now we're getting a few details. Please **edit your original question** to tell us (1) that you are building a traffic light project. (2) How many digital outputs you have. (3) How many different groups of lights you are trying to switch. (Green man = 1 group.) (4) What voltage is available for the LEDs. (5) Maximum number of LEDs in one group. (6) A link to the LED data sheet so we can calculate voltage and current.

Comment: http://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/55-1814.pdf

Comment: @transistor I have added the relevant details

Answer (score 3):

No. That chip is just a bunch of transistors with their emitters all connected to comm (pin 9). You can't do high-side switching with them.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image from [SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36629/bjt-resistor-and-diode-work-but-uln2803-does-not).*

- The ULN2803 consists of eight Darlington transistors connected to a common pin.
- Each output can switch up to 500 mA to common.
- The maximum current the common can handle is 2.5 A (but I recommend operating at 1 A max to improve reliability).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f08YJb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2.*

Arrange your groups of LEDs as shown above. Since you have a 5 V supply that's enough to power two LEDs in each string. The 47 Ω resistor will limit current to about 20 mA on each pair of LEDs so the total for a group of eight will be 80 mA. You need to check how many will be on at one time. Then make sure your power supply can supply enough mA.

If you had a few more outputs your job would be much easier. The simplest way would be to use a relay on one channel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhOAFd.png)</sup>

*Figure 3.*

The sketch above shows two groups of LEDs sharing the low-side Darlington driver. The active group is selected by the high-side relay (which can feed other pairs of groups as well). The problem with this is that you need to group any LEDs that are on at the same time on the same relay circuit because it is only a low-speed multiplexer.

It is possible to do this with high-side transistor switching and achieve high-speed multiplexing. I'll leave that to you to research.

Note that the Darlington common has to be connected to the micro ground.

---

**Current per LED**

[image: Current ratings]

*Figure 4. Absolute maximum ratings for [TruOpto 55-1814](http://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/55-1814.pdf).*

The datasheet, page 1, clearly shows the LED maximum continuous current rating as 30 mA. If the LEDs are pulsed, as in a multiplexing application such as yours, they can take 100 mA for 10 ms max. every 100 ms. If running a faster multiplexer use 100 mA for 10% of the time.

Comment: So should i connect the sinking LEDs to the 5v power suplly

Comment: Edit your **original question** to explain what you are trying to achieve, why you designed the circuit the way you did and what result you expect.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Is it possible to use a 9v supply if i keep the darlington driver on a different board as the 9v won't be passin through the pic thus not blowing it

Comment: Yes, and if you have 9 V you can put four LEDs in each string. Remember that you need to connect the 9 V common to the 5 V common.

Comment: I just realised that is what high-side transistor switching is

Comment: Won't putting the leds in series reduce the light on each led

Comment: No. LEDs brightness depends on _current_. 20 mA is enough for the type you've selected. At 20 mA about 2 V will appear across each LED. 4 * 2 = 8 V + a bit for the resistor and the Darlington. The clever bit is that you're using the same 20 mA to run 4 LEDs so now the total power for one group is 40 mA and not 160 mA as it would have been on your original design.

Comment: the darlington is atleast 0.6v leaving only 0.4V for the resitor, three in series is probably a better choice.

Comment: you probably need to use the ULB2x03 to drive the relay coil,

Comment: you talk about multiplexing, but have not drawn an example of it.

Comment: You're right. I forgot what I was demonstrating. Does it read better now?

Comment: that bit does.  still need more voltage margin and better drive for the relay.

Comment: @transistor How many amps is needed for each led

Comment: You find that sort of information in the data sheet. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @transistor If the dc forward current needed was 50mA, should i still use a 47 ohm resistor

Comment: No, you'd look up the data sheet graphs and figure out what the typical voltage across each LED is at 50 mA (or measure it).  \$R = \frac {n \cdot V_{LED} + V_{TRANS}}{I}\$ where _n_ is the number of LEDs and \$V_{TRANS}\$ is the voltage across the transistor when 'on'. \$I\$ is the current, 50 mA (0.05 A) in your case.